# Is it common practice for a company to request a background check before a job offer?

Tags: job-offer, united-states

I applied for a job in a bank. HR told me that the next step is that they would like to perform a background check on me. In my past experience with applying for a job, I have always gotten the offer letter first then was asked to do a background check. Is this practice customary for banks or am I missing something?

Comment: To me, that seems the obvious sequence... first check whether you want to hire someone, *then* make them an offer. But I know it's different elsewhere, so I guess "it depends". Can you add a country tag, to get better insights into what is customary in your country?

Comment: This is the United States.

Comment: Yes, this is usual for scammers. It's the perfect way to harvest private information of their next people. Be careful. Make sure you're talking to the people who actually work at that bank you applied to. Once you're sure they're the right people, then you can go ahead.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Can't the scammers just send a fake offer letter?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, Yes, they can, but that would be even more suspicious if the OP has only applied to the position and not been interviewed yet. And to me at least, it isn't clear from the question whether they have even been interviewed yet.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk That seems orthogonal to the question.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie, Fair enough. I just thought it was worth mentioning because I've seen this kind of question on this stackexchange before.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Yeah, I'd wait until after the interview. But either before or after the offer is made makes no difference to me.

Answer (score 11):

In my experience (US, Tech industry), the common sequence is an offer letter first, then the background check. The offer is made subject to the successful completion of the background check.

Comment: Your post seems to be contradicting itself, or maybe I can't read today..

Comment: The offer essentially says "if you pass the background check." No contradiction.

Comment: @Alrl, I agree with you. It seems a contradiction. It seems like a circular dependency. :-)

Comment: This answer contradicts itself.

Comment: Maybe you mean there is a clause in the contract that requires the successful completion of the background check.

Comment: What is so hard to understand? The offer letter says it is made contingent on passing the background check. If you pass, you get it, if you don't the offer is void.

Comment: You don't say the offer letter says it's made contingent. You clearly state the offer is made subject to a successful BG. Which means the offer may not be made if the BG check fails.

Comment: And you've made the wording slightly better, but still ambiguous.

Comment: I'm not sure why people are having trouble with the wording.  It's very clear: an offer is extended to the applicant.  The offer includes a clause that says it's contingent on a successful background check.

Comment: @DaveG That's not what it says. It says it's only given contingent on a successful background check.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie The phrase "The offer is made subject to the successful completion of the background check" means that the offer includes a contingency clause about a background check.  I'm peripherally involved in the real estate business and virtually all real estate purchase offers include such contingency clauses, and it's always phrased that way: offer is contingent on xyz.

Comment: @DaveG That may be true, but the answer does not mention clauses at all. it just says that it will be made contingent. So it's ambiguous. "I will wear my favourite dress contingent on the weather." can mean either the dress won't be worn if the weather isn't suitable, or the dress will be modified the manner in which it is worn depending on the weather.

Comment: @DaveG If an expression means something, that should be explained, rather just assume the OP knows what it means. It's obvious the OP isn't sure about this stuff, and it's clear at least 3 people are confused.

Comment: Weird arguments here. You pass the background check, you can have the job if you want. You don’t pass the check. No job.

Comment: @gnasher729 It doesn't say that. It says the offer is only made if the background check passes.

Answer (score 4):

I have worked in the financial industry starting first as a contractor, then being converted to full time. I received an offer and it was contingent upon a successful background check. This is the normal sequence of things. The FDIC requires a criminal background check to screen out people convicted of certain crimes. Most companies also verify your work and education and do a credit check. That level of background check requires a financial and time investment from the company.

They will want to ensure that you are serious about the position and let you know they are serious about hiring you before they pay for a check that can take a significant amount of time. They generally won't start the background check without some confirmation from you that you will accept the position they've offered.

If a company decides not to hire you based on the background check, legally they have to give you a copy of the report and a pre-adverse action letter. Then they have to wait a "reasonable" amount of time to give you a chance to correct any mistakes in the report before telling you they won't hire you because of the results. If they do the check without extending an offer, they may be able to legally skip over that part, but it would be shady.

It is very unusual for someone to try to do the background check before they make you an offer in the US, and I personally would not agree to it.

Comment: I find this answer useful as it explains why a background check is performed only after candidate accepts conditional offer.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response. I felt it was somewhat odd myself.

Answer (score 3):

> I applied for a job in a bank. HR told me that the next step is that
> they would like to perform a background check on me.

Background check have several types. Some places only do some of them, other places do all of them.

They can look into:

- Criminal history
- Financial history
- Drug use
- Work history

Because this is a bank they may know that what trips up the candidates is financial and criminal. It is possible that they ask you to sign all the forms to do the full background check, but then only do the ones that they can do electronically :criminal, and financial.

If you pass those initial checks then they can give you a conditional offer letter. The condition is to pass the entire background check.

Comment: Education verification (to confirm that a candidate attended the institutions and earned the degrees and certifications they claim) is another common part of background checks, and has been for more than a decade.

Answer (score 1):

It's not unusual for contracts to have clauses that invalidate the contract if the background check fails. Because background checks can take a while, it can be suitable to offer a contract before it is completed. Sometimes even employment can begin before the check is complete.

This is not always appropriate however.

With respect to your situation, there can be regulatory requirements in some industries for a background check to be completed before employment commences.

I wouldn't be surprised if a bank has a firm requirement that a background check is completed before even the contract is discussed. This ensure there is no mix-up where the check is pending, but you start work.